# Code::Blocks output "error: ld returned 1 exit status" without else

Tags: c++, opencv, boost, settings, codeblocks

My Code::Blocks IDE is calling just "error: ld returned 1 exit status" when I build my code. I frequently saw this error with "collect2:" as "collect2: ld returned 1 exit status". I just know this is linker error. So I need to include another linraries.

But I'm  inexperienced to use this IDE even if C++.

So I don't get it how I get rid of this error.

I would like to ask below things.

1)How to get rid of this error. What issues are considered.

2)How to set up Build options to suit my code in below.

**Note(Build opetions)**:
Link libraries in Linker setting is added

```
../../opencv-2.4.13/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.so

../../opencv-2.4.13/build/lib/libopencv_core.so

../../opencv-2.4.13/build/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so

pthread

boost_system
```

and, Compiler in Search directories is

```
../../opencv-2.4.13/include/opencv

../../../../usr/include/boost
```

[image: MyDesktop]

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp> 
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>   // boost/containers/vector.hpp
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>   // boost/containers/string.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 //                                                                    void_allocator;
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

typedef unsigned char uchar;
//Typedefs of allocators and containers
typedef bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager                       segment_manager_t;
typedef bip::allocator<void, segment_manager_t>  void_allocator;

typedef void_allocator::rebind<uchar>::other                           uchar_allocator;
typedef bip::vector<uchar, uchar_allocator>                                   uchar_vector;



template <typename Alloc = std::allocator<uchar> >
struct BasicInData {

    public:
        BasicInData(Alloc alloc = {}) : image(alloc)
        { }

        template <typename T>
        BasicInData(double x, int sizeImg, uchar_vector& image, Alloc alloc = {}) :
            x(x), sizeImg(sizeImg), image(alloc)
        { }

        double x = 0;
        int sizeImg = 0;
        uchar_vector image;
};

using InData = BasicInData<>; // just heap allocated

namespace Shared {
    using segment                      = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using segment_manager              = segment::segment_manager;

    template <typename T> using alloc  = bip::allocator<T, segment_manager>;
    template <typename T> using vector = bip::vector<T, alloc<T> >;

    using InData = BasicInData<alloc<uchar> >; // shared memory version

    vector<InData>& locate(segment& smt) {
        auto* v = smt.find_or_construct<vector<InData> >("InDataVector")(smt.get_segment_manager());
        assert(v);
        return *v;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc == 1){ //Parent process
        // Remove shared memory on construction and destruction

        // Create a new segment with given name and size
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        struct shm_remove
        {
            shm_remove(){bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
            ~shm_remove(){bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");}
        }remover;
        Shared::segment smt(bip::create_only,"MySharedMemory", 65536); // 10 Kb for coliru
        auto &data = Shared::locate(smt);
        //Shared::alloc bip::alloc_inst (data);

        cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> mat;
        cv::VideoCapture vcap(0);

        Shared::InData id(smt.get_segment_manager());


        if (!vcap.isOpened())
            return -1;

        while (1) {
            vcap >> mat;
            int image_size = mat.total() * mat.elemSize();
            id.sizeImg = image_size;
            id.image.resize(image_size * sizeof(uchar));
            memcpy(&id.image[0], mat.data, image_size * sizeof(uchar));
            //Launch child process
            gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
            double time = ((double)tv.tv_usec/1000000);
            id.x = time;
            data.push_back(id);
            if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
        }

        std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child";
        if(0 != std::system(s.c_str()))
            return 1;

        // check child has destroyed the vector
        if(smt.find<Shared::vector<InData>>("InDataVector").first)
            return 1;

    } else{
        // Open the managed segment
        bip::managed_shared_memory segment(bip::open_only, "MySharedMemory");

        // Find the vector using c-string name
        bip::vector<InData> *myvector = segment.find<bip::vector<InData>>("InDataVector").first;
        // Use vector in reverse order

        bip::vector<InData>::iterator it;

        cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> im;
        for(it = myvector->begin(); it !=myvector->end(); ++it){
            im.resize(it->sizeImg);
            memcpy(im.data, &it->image[0], it->sizeImg);
            cv::imshow("window1", im);
        }

        segment.destroy<bip::vector<InData>>("InDataVector");

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the "Build Log" tab show?

Comment: @greatwolf , I totally forgot it. I'm going to check up.

Comment: `undefined reference to symbol 'shm_unlink@@GLIBC_2.2.5'` in Build Log, and I need '-lrt', but still I don't get it. Could you teach me where to type in 'rt'?

Comment: You can add it under project->build options->linker settings tab.

Comment: @greatewolf  Thanks. Then, I should type in 'rt' ?, not 'lrt'?

Comment: I would try `rt` first, codeblocks should know how to pass the flag correctly

Comment: Oh, It's 'rt'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @greatwolf.
Finally, I could get rid of that error.
Now,I show the "Linker setting" in below.

```
../../opencv-2.4.13/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.so

../../opencv-2.4.13/build/lib/libopencv_core.so

../../opencv-2.4.13/build/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so

pthread

boost_system

rt
```